# Does the DeLorean have a spare tyre?

Tags: back-to-the-future, vehicles

I can't remember seeing a spare wheel for the DeLorean in *Back to the Future* (any of them).

Doc pulls his suitcase out of the front trunk but there isn't much room in the trunk space. Bearing in mind the change of wheels/tyres in 1955, would you take the risk of not having at least one spare?

Comment: Spares? Where we're going, we don't need spares.

Comment: Both trips to 1955 weren't planned ahead of time. All that was planned was a trip a minute into the future where spare wheels still exist and into a future where cars fly. While there still might be a spare, your argumentation makes little sense

Comment: The classic gull-wing delorean had a thin "space-saver" tyre *under* the bootspace (along with a small toolkit) http://delorean.co.nz/1564/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/31.jpg. There's no indication of whether the doc left it there or removed it to save weight. I see no reason why he'd have taken it out, tbh

Comment: “a trip a minute into the future where spare wheels still exist” — _as far as we know!!_

Comment: @Jenayah - good one!!

Comment: @Raditz_35 not an argument just a question! See the pic below of 1955 and there is a strange box thing on the hood. Given the weight of the car pre modifications every little bit counts. As far as only traveling 1 minute into the future Doc was planning on leaving straight after the test. Isn't this a Q&A site?

Comment: @Valorum, with the stock powertrain, getting to 88mph wouldn't be very quick, especially with all the weight of the time machine added on.  I'd suggest that he would have wanted to take everything out that was non-essential to save weight and improve performance.  It looks like a cool, fast car, but it was not a high performance machine.

Comment: As it was an American company, it could only have a spare *tire*. ;)

Comment: @jpmc26 Oh know, will I get marked down for correct spelling? It's like wearing the wrong colour in NY! :p

Comment: Also wasn't it an Irish company that made the DeLorean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeLorean_Motor_Company#Beginning Looks like it was American but put its factories in Ireland. Weird.

Comment: Makes sense, the Irish make a car that can travel through time but doesn't have a spare!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Having a spare didn't really matter because it seems that it has a common enough tire/wheel size that they were able to buy 4 new ones in 1955 for the trip back to 1885.

[image]

You are correct that the cargo space in the vehicle is small (14 cubic feet/ 0.4 cubic meters) [according the vehicle specs](http://www.backtothefuture.com/delorean/specifications). This is likely because the standard DeLorean spare tire was located under this.

[image]

[image]

There is no direct evidence that the spare was removed to accommodate parts/equipment for the time machine and considering that cargo space is still intact it is likely that the spare tire is as well.

Comment: Actually, as can be seen by the hubcaps, they seemed to have bought completely new wheels.

Comment: @SQB Yes but it would still have to match the stud bolts unless they redid the whole assembly.

Comment: @Skooba - For a skilled engineer with access to a workshop that would be the sort of thing that takes a lazy afternoon of cutting and welding

Comment: Should match the bolts, yes. But the DMC-12 has a PCD of 4 x 100, which is common enough.

Comment: Doesn't the suspension look like it's been lifted to accommodate the white walled tyres?

Comment: @Seamusthedog It was indeed (but the reason was not soley for the tires)... *[For Back to the Future Part III, two Deloreans were outfitted with special dune buggy chassis and high performance Volkswagen engines for scenes filmed in the Western terrain.](http://www.backtothefuture.com/delorean/creation)*

Comment: @Skooba Thought so, Doc was such a genius!!

Comment: @Seamusthedog Always thought the Delorean crashed through the desert scrub in rather a dune buggy-ish way.